# how to use sap-hybris media(image) url from out side- or how can link it

Tags: media, sap-commerce-cloud, backoffice

I want to use the image of sap-hybris by URL , how can get it 
Like- some URLs like:https://s3.amazonaws.com/manikart.bbb.dd/LOGO-512x512.png
in this case, I want to use the sap-hybris media but from  back-office, I only get this medias/sys_master/images/h50/h25/8855153901598/RapidHybrisLogo512512.png URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to access media manually, all you need to do is prefix it with your site URL.

Let's say
**Site URL:** https://www.test.com/mystorefront
**Media URL:** /medias/sys_master/images/h50/h25/8855153901598/RapidHybrisLogo512512.png

Now, You can access media with https://www.test.com/mystorefront/medias/sys_master/images/h50/h25/8855153901598/RapidHybrisLogo512512.png

If your requirement is to get the full media URL from the media object itself, then you can create a dynamic attribute say **fullMediaURL** in the MediaModel and write the logic to concat your basesiteURL with Media downloadURL in your dynamicAttributeProvider class.

Answer (score 0):

You can control generated media url with **LocalMediaWebURLStrategy** strategy. Extend it as your needs.